# What is the best security $_POST method?

Tags: security

I made profile page. And i am getting values directly from inputs with $_POST method. Users update their profile in this page. I wonder is this security method? And i am using this in wp_list_table too.

Comment: security is all about context and you supply none, therefor it will be impossible to have any meaningful answer to the question. If `$_POST` is insecure what will you use instead? Please edit the question and make it about some concrete code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to sanitize or escape the data based on type and application of the data. Like below-

```
$title = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['title'] );
update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title', $title );
```

It's a quite huge topic. You better read this [Validating Sanitizing and Escaping User Data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data).

Comment: You actually should not use text field sanitation before storing a value in meta field. Users are going to be upset if you mangle their names for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the WordPress functions that the_dramatist mentioned above by linking to [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data), there is also a very useful native PHP function that allows you to sanitize all data from $_POST super global at once: `filter_input_array`. See [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php). Example:

```
// let's say I'm expecting to get data like this:
$_POST = [
    'myString'         => 'Hello World',
    'myInteger'        => 42,
    'myArrayOfStrings' => [
        'hello',
        'world',
    ],
];

// sanitizing $_POST super global:

$data = filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, [
    'myString'         => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'myInteger'        => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    'myArrayOfStrings' => [
        'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
        'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY,
    ],
] );

// now $data contains array of sanitized values
```